How to Smoothly Move a Draggable Item Between Pages While Maintaining Selection in Angular?
I'm working on an Angular project where I have a draggable element that needs to move between pages. I'm using the Angular CDK Drag and Drop, and I have encountered an issue when trying to move the draggable element from one page to another. The element should move smoothly, and the selection should be maintained as it crosses the page boundary.
Here are the specific requirements:

The draggable element should move to the next page when it reaches the bottom of the current page, and similarly, it should move to the previous page when it reaches the top.
The element must maintain its selection state when transitioning between pages.
The movement between pages should be smooth, without abrupt jumps.

I've tried several approaches, including manually detecting when the element reaches the edge of the page and programmatically moving it to the next or previous page, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired smoothness and continuity.
Here's a minimal reproduction of the problem: StackBlitz Example.
How can I achieve this functionality in Angular? Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried without using the cdk?

I have not tried using other libraries

I had once to make draggable elements and din't used the cdk and never encoutered this kind of problem when navigating through divs. just use ondrop on the div you would like to drop the element in.So I'm sorry appart from that I'm not sure I can help you

btw way no need to use other libraries you have (ondrag) (ondrop)... event built in

after thinking of your problem it depends if the page is really another page or if like in your example different pages are in the body. If different pages are in the body then I don't understand why you use moveToPage method. If that not the case the minimal reproduction doesn't reproduce the desired behaviour

Sorry, I didn't understand what you proposed.
I need to keep the draggable element within a page, but it can be in any position on the page that I place it, because later I will get the x and y position of the element within the page.
To solve my problem, I need to make a component to work together with the 2D canvas of this ngx-extended-pdf-viewer component, so that I can position a signature on the page.

as said before you don't need cdk or function to move the element. If your stackblitz example is the same as your app you don't need this
